# write html syntax in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

There is something I don't understand 
I don't understand why I have `height:42px` and not `height:395px`?

When I show the code with firebug I see that

```
<form id="new_user" class="wizard" style="height: 42px;" method="post" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

but on my view I have this

```
<div class="contentbox">
    <div id="wizard", style="left: 0px; position: relative;">
        <div class="container_12 clearfix leading">
            <div class="grid12">

  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html=> { :class => "wizard",:style => 'height: 395px' }) do |f| %>
     <%= devise_error_messages! %>


                        <!-- wizard -->
                        <form action="#" class="wizard" novalidate>
                            <nav>
                                <ul class="clearfix">
                                    <li class="active"><strong>1.</strong> Identification</li>
                                    <li><strong>2.</strong> Information </li>
                                    <li><strong>3.</strong> Finalisation</li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
```

Do you have any idea why I get `height:42px` and not `height:395px`?

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to do this using stylesheets rather than inline styling but I think it is simply a matter of a missing ;

```
:html=> { :class => "wizard",:style => 'height: 395px;' }
```

If there is a clash with your stylesheets you could also put

```
:html=> { :class => "wizard",:style => 'height: 395px !important;' }
```